# Navbar item opening dropdown menu change background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

How to change background of a navbar item opening a dropdown-menu:

[image: Navbar link opening dropdow-menu]

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li>
    <a href="#/" class="dropdown-toggle nav-lang" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">FR<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="nav-lang" href="?lang=fr"><img height="15" src="/images/navbar-fr.png"><span class="pad-l-10 fnt-rob pad-t-10">English</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS I tried with no success:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a.nav-lang .active {
  background:#93b874 !important;
}
```

`#93b874` is the green color, actually I don't want background color when we click on this item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any space after the `.`:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a.nav-lang.active
//---------------------------^^ Remove the space here.
```

When the space is given, it looks for a child element to apply the styles for.

And give `background: none transparent;` if needed with `!important`.

Looks like the answer lies in:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a.nav-lang { background:none transparent !important; }
```

Comment: @LondonSmith Can you quickly show a [mcve] or a demo please?

Comment: It's only on localhost for now. It's strange but it works without active: `.navbar-nav > li > a.nav-lang {
    background:none transparent !important;
}
`

Comment: @LondonSmith Made your question look better as well.